# UiPath deserialize current JSON Object Error on testing any activity

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio

[image]Hi I am trying to run a simple login workflow in uipath and while running the workflow as **"Test Activity"** it is throwing the below exception
**I have encountered similar exception in other languages but not seen this in UIPath.**

```
 Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'UiPath.Service.Api.Service.Models.FlowControl.IFlowControlAction[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
    To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
    Path 'DebugOptions.FlowControlActions.Value', line 1, position 18798.
```

Comment: Show us your activity. And show what the ingoing argument is like. And the setting parameters of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by deleting the latest version of uipath studio was 2021 and was automatically uploaded by uipath.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, please consider to upload pictures.